# Bootstrap 3 - affix is not changing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I have a button which opens a modal. This button should always be visible. If the user scrolls down the page, the button should be "affixed" on top.

I use bootstrap v3.1.1 and the [affix.js](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) is loaded in the head and is attaching the **"affix-top"** class to my button like it should.

But when I scroll - I have tried several variants of implmentation - the *affix-top* class is not changing to *affix*.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-t-10 m-b-10"
            id="standard-questions-button"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#standard-questions-modal">
      Show Questions
    </button>
```

JS:

```
$('#standard-questions-button').affix({
    offset: {top: $('#standard-questions-button').position().top}
});

// for testing only
$('#standard-questions-button').on('affix.bs.affix', function () {
    alert('affix');
})
```

CSS:

```
#standard-questions-button.affix-top {
  color: red;
  position: static;
  margin-top:25px;
  width:228px;
}

#standard-questions-button.affix {
  color: green;
  top:25px;
  float: right;
  width:228px;
}
```

---

Approach 2 (also not working: wrapped in a function)

```
   $('#standard-questions-button').affix({
        offset: {top: function(){return $('#standard-questions-button').position().top}}
    });
```

- How can I solve this?
- Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you prepare the https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Very strange, the fiddle works like expected... https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0szvwe/

Comment: With your second approach, with the function, try to also `console` the value of `$('#standard-questions-button').position().top` there is a slight possibility that your JS executes before your CSS loads and you get a wrong `top` value.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. Maybe you have the similar problem.

In bootstrap script (I use the version 2.3.2) there is a code fragment that assigns event handler to the window's scroll:

```
     this.$window = $(window)
    .on('scroll.affix.data-api', $.proxy(this.checkPosition, this))
```

I realized that in my code the scroll event wasn't fired at all so the class was not being changed. When I changed only this fragment for:

```
     this.$window = $('#main_container')
    .on('scroll.affix.data-api', $.proxy(this.checkPosition, this))
```

It finally started to work. Just check what is the element you are scrolling on your webpage and set it in bootstrap's Affix function definition.

You may find helpful this to check if you are able to scroll through window:

```
    $( window ).scroll(function() {
      alert("scroll");
    });
```